# Positioning last child drop-down menu in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The drop-down menu works fine on my theme but just have little problem for last-child submenu like about fix the text position cannot move to top nearby another submenu and about how to remove transparency background for last child submenu  like my concept below: 
[image: drop-down menu]

**css for drop-down menu**

```
.navbar-default {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
    background: #fff;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdâ€¦IxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjdG9wVG9Cb3R0b21HcmFkaWVudCkiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e6e6e6 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(100%, #e6e6e6));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e6e6e6 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e6e6e6 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0, #e6e6e6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #e6e6e6 100%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}

.navbar-nav {
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0
}

.navbar-nav a {
    display: block;

}

.navbar-nav li {
    display: block;
    /* margin: 0 47%; */
    padding: 0;
    /* width: 180px; */
    /* height: 138px; */
    /* text-indent: -999em; */
    direction: ltr;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 105px;
    visibility: visible;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: transparent;
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: -33px auto 0 auto;
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    /* text-indent: -999em; */
    direction: ltr;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%;
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin: -33px auto 0 auto;
     width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    direction: ltr;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: transparent;   
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
   background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%;
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin: -33px auto 0 auto;
     width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    direction: ltr;
    float: none;
    }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%;
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin: -33px auto 0 auto;
     width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    direction: ltr;
    float: none;

}


.navbar-nav ul {
}

.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:hover, .nav .open>a:focus {
    /* background-color: #eeeeee; */
    border-color: #337ab7;

}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin: -1px 0 0 45%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;

}

.dropdown-menu {
    /* background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 91% 100%; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 153px;
    padding: 1px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5c4d4a;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
    display: block;
    background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 104% 108%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li a:focus {
    background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 104% 108%;
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff428bca', endColorstr='#ff357ebd', GradientType=0);
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
    display: block;
    background: url(img/submenu.png) no-repeat scroll right/ 104% 108%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.dropdown-menu   li:last-child a:hover,
.dropdown-menu   li:last-child a:focus
 {

    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff428bca', endColorstr='#ff357ebd', GradientType=0);
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu ul { 

list-style: none; 

}
```

For further info you can check out [my theme](http://dev.galerigadget.com/). Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put text on top you can change your `.dropdown-menu li:last-child a` to something like:

```
.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 52px;
}
```

If you want to remove transparent background but you have menu shadow in `.dropdown-menu` must add this rules at the bottom:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    ...

    border-bottom-right-radius: 77px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 77px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
    padding: 31px 20px;
}
```

to

```
.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the desired effect you can just:

```
.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
     padding: 8px 20px 62px 20px
}
```